# Using wrong ruby version after rvm ruby install of 2.2.4

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Background: I am on a mac os X. I installed ruby 2.2.4 using RVM.

When I try to bundle install I get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/bundle: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

`which ruby` returns `.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby`.

`whereis ruby` returns `/usr/bin/ruby`

I looked online for a solution and the editing the line of brew.rb from 1.8 to Current is not to be found anywhere. Maybe this file has changed.

I tried the brew update with no luck as well. Any clue what the issue is?

Comment: does it happen for all `bundle install`s?

Comment: Switch into new version with `rvm use ....` and the do `gem install bundler` the first time. It should work

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your brew using  `brew upgrade`. Then install rvm and install the ruby.

Comment: rvm is already installed. should I do "rvm implode" and install it again?

Comment: yeah sure you do that.

Comment: bit strage but you can try with .rvmrc and overwriting the path.

Comment: yes. After a day decided to delete all and install xcode, libs, ruby, rvm and rails from scratch. works fine now. I was in a hurry with a project and couldn't spend more time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .rvmrc file in your project root
by doing:

> touch .rvmrc

then edit the file adding this single line:

> rvm use ruby-2.2.4@yourprojectname --create

restart the terminal, open your project folder again and type:
ruby -v

ps: make sure your terminal is running as login shell